# ¿Cómo trabajar con más de una fuente de datos en Android (Clean Architecture con UseCases)?

Tags: android, repositorio, usecase

En mi aplicación necesito reflejar lo siguiente:

1. Verificar si un determinado dato se encuentra en Firestore
2. Si no se encuentra allí, buscarlo en mi sitio web

Si he entendido bien lo que he leído sobre *Clean Architecture*, estaríamos hablando de **dos fuentes de datos**.

Yo he programado código por separado, y puedo obtener datos de ambas fuentes de datos, mi problema está en el diseño correcto para implementarlo mediante UseCases (apenas empiezo con esto de *Clean Architecture* y muchos conceptos son desconocidos para mi).

Aquí dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora. La obtención de datos desde la Api ya la tengo metida en el UseCase, y funciona:

### En el `UseCase`:

```
public class GetComentariosUseCase extends SingleUseCase<Comentario, GetComentariosUseCase.Params>{

    private static ComentariosRepository mRepository;

    @Inject
    public GetComentariosUseCase(ComentariosRepository repository){
        mRepository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    protected Single<Comentario> buildUseCaseSingle(Params params) {
        return mRepository.getComentarios(params.theDate);
    }

    public static class Params{
        String theDate;
        public Params(String theDate){
            this.theDate = theDate;
        }
    }
}
```

### En el `ViewModel`:

```
public void getComentarios(String theDate) {
    _progressLiveData.postValue(true);
    getComentariosUseCase.execute(new GetComentariosUseCase.Params(theDate), new SingleUseCaseCallback<Comentario>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Comentario mData) {
            mMutableLiveData.postValue(mData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            _errorLiveData.postValue(new Event(t.getLocalizedMessage()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinished() {
            _progressLiveData.postValue(false);
        }
    });
}
```

### El `Repository` es una interfaz:

```
public interface ComentariosRepository {

    Single<Comentario> getComentarios(String theDate);
}
```

### Aquí la implementación:

```
public class ComentariosRepoImp implements ComentariosRepository {

    ApiService apiService;

    @Inject
    public ComentariosRepoImp(ApiService apiService){
        this.apiService = apiService;
    }

    @Override
    public Single<Comentario> getComentarios(String theDate) {
        return apiService.getComentarios(theDate);
    }
}
```

### En la Vista (Fragmento):

```
    cViewModel.getComentarios("20210821");
    cViewModel.mData.observe(
            this, mData ->
            binding.includeTv.tvClickable.setText(mData.getComentarioCompleto())
    );
    cViewModel.errorLiveData.observe(this , new EventObserver<>(s -> {
        Log.d("TAG",s);
    }));
```

---

Ahora pasamos a mi primera fuente de datos, que sería Firestore. Ahora mismo estoy usando este código para obtener los datos desde Firestore. Este código también funciona, ahora mismo es llamado desde un repositorio y quiero llevarlo al UseCase.

```
public MutableLiveData<Comentario> comentarioListening(String theDate, String hourId) {

    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference document = firestore.document(theDate);
    RxFirestore.observeDocumentRef(document)
            .subscribe(metaDoc -> {
                String theHour = String.format("lh.%s", hourId);
                DocumentReference dataRef = metaDoc.getDocumentReference(theHour);
                MetaLiturgia meta = metaDoc.toObject(Today.class).getMetaLiturgia();

                RxFirestore.observeDocumentRef(dataRef)
                        .subscribe(mData -> {
                            Comentario comentario = mData.toObject(Comentario.class);
                            comentario.setMetaLiturgia(meta);
                            theData.setValue(comentario);
                        }, throwable -> {
                            Log.e("RxFirebaseSample*", throwable.getMessage());
                        });
            });
    return theData;
}
```

Como ya dije, ambas cosas funcionan. Pero, ¿**cómo incorporo la obtención de datos desde Firestore, para decidir, desde el UseCase, qué datos mostrar** según lo dicho al principio? Es decir, buscar primero en Firestore y si no hay datos buscarlos en la Api.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda al respecto, así como cualquier corrección si estoy enfocando mal el problema. Como ya dije, apenas me estoy adentrando en *Clean Architecture* y hay muchísimos conceptos que todavía no domino.

### Notas:

1. Estoy usando Hilt para la inyección de dependencias
2. Para las llamadas a la Api uso Retrofit / RXJava
3. Para mapear los resultados de Firestore uso [esta librería](https://github.com/FrangSierra/RxFirebase) basada en RXJava.

Comment: La decisión de obtener los datos de una fuente u otra debería ir en el repositorio, de esa forma la capa superior (UseCase) se mantiene separada de la lógica de recuperación de datos. Te comparto una imagen de referencia, es una arquitectura más simple pero el concepto se mantiene https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/images/final-architecture.png

Comment: Como te han dicho en el comentario anterior, el repository pattern se encarga de la lógica de acceso a datos.  Entonces al repositorio se le inyecta dos datasources: Uno que comunique con la api y otro que comunique con el firestore.  El repositorio de la api recibe la interfaz de retrofit por constructor y el repositorio de firestore recibe la instancia de firestore.  El repo debe tener un mapper del modelo de respuesta al modelo de dominio.  Y la interfaz del repositorio debe estar en el dominio.  Te recomiendo leer Clean Architecture, todo ésto está explicado.